# Select latest row per group having date less than specified date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

This is a bit of a tricky one, but I have a table that looks like:

```
Time                  Meter   Value
2018-09-15 11:00:00   IU       0.105
2018-09-15 11:00:00   GD       1.648
2018-09-10 10:00:00   OU      -0.018
2018-09-10 10:00:00   GD       1.659
2018-09-01 19:00:00   OU       0.003
2018-09-01 19:00:00   OD       2.188
2018-09-01 19:00:00   IU       0.096
2018-09-01 19:00:00   GD       1.670
```

For any given time, I want to get the closest previous value for each distinct meter:  e.g: for time "2018-09-14 12:00:00" I want to get:

```
2018-09-10 10:00:00 OU  -0.018
2018-09-10 10:00:00 GD  1.659
2018-09-10 04:15:00 KD  0.737
2018-09-01 19:00:00 IU  0.096
```

I initially thought that this query might work:

```
SELECT `meter`, max(`time`) time, `value` 
FROM `data` 
WHERE `time`<= '2018-09-15 12:00:00' 
GROUP BY `meter`;
```

It gave the expected times, but different values.

I then thought that the best way of doing it would be to use this query as a basis and then run another query using the output:

```
SELECT `meter`, max(`time`) time 
FROM `data` 
WHERE `time`<= '2018-09-15 12:00:00' 
GROUP BY `meter`;
```

Output:

```
2018-09-10 10:00:00 OU
2018-09-10 10:00:00 GD
2018-09-10 04:15:00 KD
2018-09-01 19:00:00 IU
```

Then on each of the rows, run:

```
SELECT `value` 
FROM `data` 
where `time` = '...' AND `meter` - '...';
```

The question is then, how can I roll it into one query such that a third columns is added which contains the result of the second query, for each of the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest method is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT d.meter, max(d.time) as time,
       (SELECT d2.value
        FROM data d2
        WHERE d2.meter = d.meter AND
              d2.time <= '2018-09-14 12:00:00'
        ORDER BY d2.time DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS value
FROM data d
WHERE d.time <= '2018-09-14 12:00:00'
GROUP BY d.meter;
```

Unless, of course, you are using MySQL 8.0.  In that case, `lag()` is the best solution:

```
select d.*, lag(value) over (partition by meter order by time) as prev_value
from data d;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  The full query that worked had these tweaks:

`select d.lock, max(d.time),`
...
 `d2.time <= '2018-09-15 12:00:00'`
...
`from data d`
`WHERE d.time <= '2018-09-15 12:00:00'`
`GROUP BY d.lock;`

The only weird thing that happens is that `prev_value` has the floating point rounding issue, so it comes out as "0.0949999988079071" rather than 0.095...

Comment: @lels Note that we normally use the phrase 'thanks a bunch' sarcastically, to mean 'thanks for nothing'

Comment: @Strawberry - ah, my bad!

Comment: @lels . . . I don't think anything in this code would change the type of `value` . . . unless something strange is going one due to the `GROUP BY`.